# Why is this relative source binding to a property in usercontrol code-behind failing?

Tags: wpf, binding

```
 <MenuItem Header="{Binding Hello, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type v:ProjectElementView}}}" />
```

v:ProjectElementView is the type of the usercontrol.

I have also tried naming the usercontrol and using an ElementName binding.

**--Edit--**

UserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl>
<Grid>        
    <TabControl>            
        <TabControl.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Hello, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type v:ProjectElementView}}}" />
                        </ContextMenu>         
        </TabControl.ContextMenu>
</Grid>
```

UserControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ProjectElementView : UserControl
{
    private string _hello = "hello";

    public string Hello
    {
        get { return _hello; }
        set { _hello = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to see the full declaration of the user control, not just the MenuItem excerpt.  Also, in the Output window of Visual Studio you should have the binding error; can you provide that text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of approaches that seems to be working

```
<UserControl x:Name="sample" >
<Grid>
    <TabControl DataContext="{Binding ElementName=sample}" >
        <TabControl.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu >
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Hello}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </TabControl.ContextMenu>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

or

```
<UserControl>
<Grid>
    <TabControl  >
        <TabControl.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu >
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Hello}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </TabControl.ContextMenu>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

again the point is you cannot access the code behind properties without setting a datacontext.But i recommend you to move your property to a viewmodel class and bind to that class.This gives you more flexibility.

Just Check this link for more

http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2007/10/wpf-tips-8-use-your-code-behind-for.html

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this won't be as simple as I expected.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                    AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Message}" />
```

EDIT

> The RelativeSource property is used to specify as a source an object that is positioned relatively to the current object
>   For more check [here](http://www.wpfwiki.com/Default.aspx?Page=WPF%20Q5.3&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

The point is i don't think you will be able to access a non datacotext property using RelativeSource

Comment: Still does not work. And the prop I want to bind to is not in the UserControl's datacontext.

Comment: Ugh. Is the same thing causing the binding using ElementName to fail? Is there a work around?